# After successful export,RCP application is not launching in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, eclipse-kepler

I've created one eclipse RCP application in Kepler.While exporting I've also changed the "Target Platform" to ECLIPSE_HOME.The application is exported successfully.While exporting I've selected multiple platform linux.x86_64 and linux.x86.

But while launching in Ubuntu it is giving the following error,

**The executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library**

Please provide your suggestions to fix the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you should have ended up with two RCP builds, one 32 bit and one 64 bit. You need to run the one that matches the installed JVM.

Comment: Yes,I am launching linux.gtk.x86_64 deliverable in Ubuntu 64 bit platform.Still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: It is the Java JVM that matters - that must be 64 bit as well